# Is "administrate" a valid English verb? What's the difference between it and "administer"?

Tags: verbs, differences, is-it-a-word

We had an interesting discussion yesterday about the use of *administer* and *administrate*.

I feel that there is a case for both usages -- sometimes you might administer something, and other times you might administrate something -- but I couldn't convince my fellow co-worker who thought that *administrate* was some kind of neo-abomination. This was mainly because I couldn't cite a convincing example.

So then, is *administrate* an acceptable verb, and what usages exist that differentiate it from *administer*?

Comment: I think you would have to come up with the use case *first*. Once a use case has been found, then we can ask if we need the word. Until then, I'll choose to regard "administrate" as shoddy jargon. So there.

Comment: Even cursory research shows that *administrate* is a well-established word; and a bit more reading confirms that in modern usage, it’s not just a redundant synonym of *administer*.

Comment: @PLL - *irregardless* is well established too.  Still a crappy word.  What is "administrate" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Malvolio: It seems to be shoddy jargon [in use at least since the 1640s, and on both sides of the Atlantic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22administrate%22+OR+%22administrates%22+OR+%22administrated%22+OR+%22administrating%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22administrate%22+OR+%22administrates%22+OR+%22administrated%22+OR+%22administrating%22&safe=off&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1550,cd_max:1749).

Comment: @hippietrail -- [so what?](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lxrlekvHZD1r3kg2r.jpg)

Comment: In computer jargon, if you have an administration screen that allows you to administ* hardware, software, files, how would you fill in the *. Administrate feels more correct to me.

Comment: I administrate the injections. I administer the injections. Two completely different meanings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the only thing that springs to mind is that *administer* is maybe more common in the sense of *give (out)*. So if you want to avoid connotation with that meaning, "administrate" could serve this purpose (though you could also *manage*, *organise*, *steer*...).

Just possibly *administrate* suggests more closer being an *administrator* in the sense of it being one's job title/function (as opposed to just administering something on an ad-hoc basis).

So apart from that, it may just depend on whether you like the sound of verbs ending in -ate.

Comment: I use *administer* for both, but I actually think this is how these different words are used. You'd never hear of doctors administrating drugs, they always administer them. But when people are groping for the word for what administrators do, *administrate* is what gets used.

Comment: +1.  Searching various newspapers as a guide to well-edited modern usage (the Guardian, Telegraph, NY Times, and LA Times) confirms this distinction: you usually *administer* a drug, but *administrate* a business.  The exception is in the NY Times, which seems to comprehensively shun *administrate* — I guess it must be vetoed somewhere in their style guide as, if not a neologism, then perhaps awkward or ugly.

Answer (score 5):

"Administrate" [appears to have a history going back almost 400 years](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/administrate) (rather to my surprise), and is an exact synonym for administer.

Comment: +1, just because I assumed it was some irritating back-formation and now stand corrected :)

Comment: I downvoted for the lack of evidence in your answer (a link is insufficient), but the 'is an exact synonym' warrants its own downvote. There are enough Google hits for "administer diamorphine" to consider it as an acceptable usage, but the one hit for "administrate diamorphine" does not license this usage. The fact that a dictionary defines a word using a synonym does not mean that it is saying that the two words are freely interchangeable; this is rarely (if ever) the case.

Comment: If I were to do this again, I would add the info as a comment, or flesh it out to be a real answer.

Answer (score 4):

The NOAD reports that *administrate* is a less common term for *administer*, when it is used to mean "manage and be responsible for the running of a business, organization, etc."

*Administrate* has been first used in the sixtenth century, and it derives from the Latin *administrat* (*administrated*), from the verb *administrare*.
*Administer* has been first used in Middle English, and it derives from the Old French word that comes from the Latin *administrare*.

Answer (score 2):

The word, "administrate" is indeed listed in Merriam-Webster as a verb. However, I would use “administer,” which is the more common/usual word. In the business world, “administrate” often has the connotation of work handled by a secretary, not a professional.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that in the tech world they favor administrate.  If you have admin. Privileges on a server, file directory, forums etc. you tend to administrate rather than administer.