# Administrating vs Admining

Tags: meaning, differences, past-participles, present-participles

I get the sense that the word "Admining", like the word "Admin" from which it derives, is used to refer to computer administration, while "Administrating", like "Administrator", is used more when it is finance or buisness being admin'd.  I would like to know what other people think, though, if that is indeed so, or if my perception is wrong.

Also, as a side note, what about "admined" vs "admin'd".

Comment: Though I'm sure Bradd's adminned is used (and preferable to "admined" which would be pronounced "ad mined"), I like "admin'd" since the apostrophe takes the place of the omitted letters in the full word, "administered".

Comment: I'd like "admin'ed" with that **e** as well.

Comment: "The True Gamers Invitational, or TGi for short, was a LAN event held in April 1999 in Gothenburg, Sweden **admined** by Izn0." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuakeWorld#1999_-_TGi)  [emphasis mine]

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/is-administrate-a-valid-english-verb-whats-the-difference-between-it-and-ad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual English verb for supervision is [*administer.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/administer) The variant forms [*administrate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/administrate) and [*admin*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/admin) are both used primarily in technical jargon, mostly in reference to computer system administration. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=administer,administrate,admin_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that they see very little use in general English compared to *administer.*

It's not at all unusual to use *-’d* instead of *-ed* for forming the [past tense of an abbreviation](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/do-you-use-an-apostrophe-to-make-OK-past-tense.aspx), especially for acronyms. *Admined* is awkward because there's (secondary) stress on the second syllable: *admin'd* or *adminned* would be preferable so that people don't read it as rhyming with *mined.*

Answer (score 3):

***Admining*** is not found in [Chambers](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/), [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=admining) or [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english/admining?showCookiePolicy=true) dictionaries, nor in [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/admining). I had never previously heard of it.

On the other hand, ***Admin***, I would say, is now in common usage in many areas of life and I certainly hadn't thought of it as being used primarily in computing administration. Nor have I ever seen it used as a verb, as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Admining* is a slang term from administrating (see [administrate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/administrate)). It is popular in online gaming and social communities. *Administrating* is the proper term to use, as well as *administrated* or *administrate*. You have the right mindset; just keep in mind that *admining* is not an official word.

Usually you will only see this usage:

> I admin a page on facebook.
>
> I am an admin on that server.

The following are acceptable for informal chat:

> I am admining this server.
>
> I admin'd that facebook page.

Comment: _Administrating_ is still jargon, and only slightly favored over _adminning._ The usual English verb is _administering._ Also, the idea of an “official word” is controversial.

Comment: *Administrating* is mainstream.