# Administer or administrate?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I'm writing a book, and I'm having trouble wording this:

> "I have a forum to **__**," he said as he walked out the door.

Should the blank be filled in with *administer* or *administrate*?

Comment: You may find some useful information [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115422/administrating-vs-admining).

Answer (score 3):

ODO has

> [**administrate**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/administrate) *verb*
>
> less common term for **administer** (sense 1).
>      *the person administrating the database system has left the company*
>      *the cost of administrating VAT*
>
> mid 16th century: from Latin *administrat-* 'managed', from the verb *administrare* (see **administer**)
>
> ---
>
> [**administer**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/administer) *verb*
>   [*with object*]
>
> **1** manage and be responsible for the running of (a business, organization, etc.):
>      *each school was administered separately*
>      • be responsible for the implementation or use of (law or resources):
>         *a Health and Safety agency would administer new regulations*
>
> late Middle English: via Old French from Latin *administrare,* from *ad-* 'to' + *ministrare* (see **ministration**)

I would rather use the older, more common form ***administer*** than the johnny-come-lately word; but even that has been around for 400 years.